# Adding an optional non-model field via Django core serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am trying to serialize a DJango queryset object.

```
data = Data.objects.filter(name__icontains='John')
data_list = serializers.serialize('json', data, fields=('name', 'title'))
return HttpResponse(data_list, content_type="application/json")
```

STDOUT of data_list

```
[{"pk": 4, "model": "XXX", "fields": {"name": "John ad", "title": "Mr. "}}]
```

In the output list I also want to add a dummy field with some hardcoded values.

STDOUT of data_list

```
[{"pk": 4, "model": "XXX", "fields": {"name": "John ad", "title": "Mr. ", "Dummy": "Value"}}]
```

Any help on how I should proceed or any links I should read would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is just annotate your queryset with this dummy value. Using [Value expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions)

```
from djanog.db.models import Value
data = Data.objects.filter(name__icontains='John').annotate(dummy=Value('Value'))
data_list = serializers.serialize('json', data, fields=('name', 'title', 'dummmy'))
```

Another way is wrap your queryset in generator:

```
def qs_with_dummy(queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        obj.dummy = 'Value'
        yield obj

data = qs_with_dummy(Data.objects.filter(name__icontains='John'))
data_list = serializers.serialize('json', data, fields=('name', 'title', 'dummy')
```

Comment: In annotate, if I put any string, I am getting attribute lookup error.

Comment: Ah. But I don't think Value is available in Django 1.6.

Comment: @Pattu Read update. Wrap your queryset in generator and add this value on the fly

Comment: Serializer only gets [object model local fields](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/base.py#L100) Your first approach is not valid, `dummy` is not in localfields.